# How to access submodel layers encapsulated in Time distributed layer in Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, vgg-net

I have developed a model that consists of extracting spatial features from video frames using VGG-19 and, from these spatial features, extracting temporal features using LSTM.
For this purpose, I have encapsulated the VGG-19 algorithm in a Time distributed layer.
Below is the code that builds the model.

```py
# Extract spatial features with VGG-19
vgg19_extract_features = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

# Be able to train some VGG-19 layers
for layer in vgg19_extract_features.layers[:frozen_layers]:
    layer.trainable = False

#Create model encapsulating VGG-19 in Time Dsitributed Layer and adding LSTM and dense layers
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(vgg19_extract_features, input_shape=(sequence_length, 224, 224, 3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(GlobalAveragePooling2D()))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_units[0], return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_units[1]))
model.add(Dense(dense_units[0], activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(dense_units[1], activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

#Compile model
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']
```

This model compiles perfectly.
However, I am now trying to create a submodel to be able to extract the output from the VGG-19 sublayers. To do this, we can first check the layers that make up the main model:

```py
for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer.name)
```

> As a result:
> `time_distributed time_distributed_1 lstm lstm_1 dense dense_1 dense_2`

And the layers within VGG-19:

```py
for layer in model.layers[0].layer.layers:
    print(layer.name)
```

> As a result:
> *`input_1`
> `block1_conv1`
> `block1_conv2`
> `block1_pool`
> `block2_conv1`
> `block2_conv2`
> `block2_pool`
> `block3_conv1`
> `block3_conv2`
> `block3_conv3`
> `block3_conv4`
> `block3_pool`
> `block4_conv1`
> `block4_conv2`
> `block4_conv3`
> `block4_conv4`
> `block4_pool`
> `block5_conv1`
> `block5_conv2`
> `block5_conv3`
> `block5_conv4`
> `block5_pool`*

However, when I want to create a submodel to get the output of the VGG-19 layers with a statement like:

```py
partial_model = Model(inputs=model.layers[0].layer.layers[0], outputs=model.layers[0].layer.layers[20].output)
```

The error is constantly displayed: ***ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor***.

I understand that this is because when encapsulating a model, inside a Time Distributed Layer, Tensor Flow is not able to access those sublayers. However, I have not found an alternative way to mediate the problem, so I am grateful for any possible solution or help.

Best regards and thanks in advance.